# Java - How to write my own exception which looks for a paticular error

Tags: java

Ive seen other questions on here that ask how to impliment your own exception but dont specify how to check for an exception. What i mean by that is, for example I want an exception to occur when a number entered is the number 10. How would I write my own exception to check if the number is 10 and throw an exception if it is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (input == 10) throw new MyWhateverException()`

Comment: `"How would I write my own exception to check..."` -- You don't, and your main problem could be that you've got things conceptually backwards. The exception doesn't "check" for anything, but rather is thrown by non-exception code that discovers the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing a custom `Exception` in your code:

```
if(input == 10){ throw new WrongNumberException("You have entered 10");}
```

Creating Your custom `Exception` class:

```
class WrongNumberException extends Exception{

    public WrongNumberException()
    {
     super();
    }

    public WrongNumberException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Key points

1.) Extend the Runtime Exception class or Exception class itself.

2.) Check for input, if 10 throw an exception with proper message.

```
public class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {

public ValidationException() {
        super();
    }

 public ValidationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

public ValidationException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

public ValidationException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

**Main class**

```
if(input == 10){ throw new ValidationException("Number Entered is 10");}
```