# Which is better ? Many custom exception classes, or one exception class with many custom exception codes?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception

In a standard J2EE web application , assuming that class load times during app startup is not an issue, which would be a better approach in terms of maintainance, performace and usability ?

The first approach involves creating different exception classes, each to denote a particular error that occurs in the application. The class names are self explanatory, and that'll be used to provide error messages.
(UPDATE : The number of classes is about 30 as of now, and it'll continue to increase in the near future, probably upto 70 or 80 atmost)

The secodn approach involves creating one exception class, and a bunch of exception codes where each code represent a particular error in the app. The error codes are obtained from the exception, and is used to provide error messages.

Comment: Creating different exceptions is always more clean. If you want , you can catch "Exception" afterwards. But as a developer, what according to you should be more preferable ? What makes you think will make your code more manageable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more or less dependent on your `business needs`.
From my point of view, having multiple custom exception classes is the right approach to go.

Learn from Java, how many it manages.

In any given application there can be `n type of validations`, **few can be clubbed under one group, few into another, but fitting everything into single does not solve the purpose** in terms of logic and business.

let say,

**UserAuthenticationException**

Cases it can cover up, and give different error messages for different cases.

1.) Invalid username/passwords

2.) Session timeout

3.) Multiple active token of same user in different machines etc...

Later playing with **instanceof** or creating **handlers** of say different exception classes is much more easier rather playing with messages.

Comment: The "multiple exception class" approach is the one I'm about to adopt. But, I'm little concerned that the number of exception classes might keep on increasing over time ( I haven't designed the entire scheme yet. We will define more exception classes as the development goes on ). And, I'm also using custom **handlers** to catch those exceptions. I'm also concerned about use of **instanceOf** and **isInstance()**. Some say it's bad practice to use them, while some says it's good. I noticed instanceOf used in a few common core Java classes, and estimated that it can't be _that bad_.

Comment: @Barath as i mentioned in my answer, in any give product/existing application, exception will never increase exponentially, infact it is the error message that increases. for eg, once u hve created say  `UserAuthenticationException` then all future validations related to user login actions etc will cover up under this one. Similary there can be `BusinessValidationException` which may cover up your other validations like form validations etc.

Comment: @Barath i just gave you example for `instanceOf`, there are other ways to catch them globally, Spring framework provides it own mechanism, rest we can always dig in and find. There is always a soultion to any problem.

Comment: In your answer, you mentioned that a single exception can be used to give different error messages on different cases. Is that done by using a flag variable or something , and mapping that variable to the error message ?

Comment: @Barath messages should be passed as constructor arguments, no flags or extra variables required. something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921281/java-how-to-write-my-own-exception-which-looks-for-a-paticular-error/26921315#26921315)

Comment: I wouldn't want to pass the message as a constructor argument. In my requirement, the error messages will not be passed through program code. They will be stored in a separate resource bundle, and they'll be looked up based on the type of exception thrown. If i had specific exceptions for each specific error occuring in the app, i can map the exception name to the required error message. (So, to lookup the message, i'll use Exception's name) . But, it won't work if a single exception is used for different cases.

Answer (score 0):

The choice is ultimately up to you, as both can be valid. I personally find it is better to make many custom exceptions, particularly if they are going to be used multiple times for the simple fact that if I want to change the error code or message a certain type of exception "File did not successfully upload" or "Item not found" or whatever the case may be, I only have to do it in one place, the custom exception, and not in every place which uses it.

This also allows you do catch those specific exceptions as the are thrown in other parts of your code. Perhaps you need to do extra work if the exception was a "File not found" exception, in which case you can catch only those exceptions that you want to handle in different ways - this would be much more difficult if they were all the same class.

Classes exists in OOP for a reason and you should take advantages of those reasons.

Answer (score 0):

From the code maintabaility point of view, the first approach, as it results in cleaner/simpler code. The name of the exception class gives you the cause of the problem without having to inspect the attributes of the exception class.

From the performance point of view, the second approach, "fewer exception classes mean a smaller
memory footprint and less time spent loading classes" (Effective Java, item 60). Keep in mind however, that "premature optimization is the root of all evil" so until you confirm your application has performance issues do not try to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Most exceptions within an application are handled by some generic recovery; probably involving generating a log file and killing or restarting the process.  There's no reason for these to be different types.

In the less usual case where a specific recovery procedure is expected, there should be a specific error class for that procedure.